# Why spinner is so big?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm developing an Android application and I have a problem with designing layouts:

With this layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUploadPhotos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/layout_upload_photos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinUploadPhotos"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@drawable/spin_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the `spin_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/select" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/select"/>
</selector>
```

I get this:

[image]

`@drawable/select` is this one:

[image]

**How can set spinner size to `@drawable/select` height?**

Comment: Could you try without `layout_weight` attribute?

Comment: set constant for layout_height.

Comment: I've tried without `layout_weight` and I get the same.

Comment: On which android version is happening this?

Answer (score 2):

Use 9 patch as background of your spinner. I think this will be interesting for you: http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

You image seems to be the culprit. If you can't use a 9-patch png, try setting the height attribute of the spinner to a better value. Perhaps, right now, you have set it to wrap_content.

Or, may be you can try reducing the height of the image itself.